# Select from two tables with operation in Oracle results in incomplete expectations

Tags: sql, oracle, select

In Oracle Express I have to tables:

TABLE1

```
BUDGET_CATEGORY     START_AMOUNT
travel              10000
expenses            20000   
equipment           15000
```

TABLE2

```
ID_EXPENSES     COST        BUDGET_CATEGORY
city bus        50          travel
car rent        120         travel
computer        800         equipment
```

I want to produce a view that will display how much money is left in each budget categories.

If I do this:

```sql
select  TABLE1.BUDGET_CATEGORY as BUDGET_CATEGORY,
        TABLE1.START_AMOUNT as START_AMOUNT,
        TABLE2.COST as COST,
        (START_AMOUNT - COST) as AVAILABLE
from    TABLE1 TABLE1,
        TABLE2 TABLE2
where   TABLE1.BUDGETCATEGORY=TABLE2.BUDGETCATEGORY
order by CATEGORY;
```

I obtain the following:

```
BUDGET_CATEGORY     START_AMOUNT        AVAILABLE
travel              10000               9830
equipment           15000               14200
```

I would like to have a view where all budget categories are listed, even the ones where no purchase were done yet, that way this view would show me some kind of a report showing all available money for all categories.

So this is what I would like to obtain:

```
BUDGET_CATEGORY     START_AMOUNT        AVAILABLE
travel              10000               9830
expenses            20000               20000
equipment           15000               14200
```

What do I need do to obtain this?

Comment: You need an outer join.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `SUM` the `cost` for each `budget_category` and then use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
select  T1.BUDGET_CATEGORY,
        T1.START_AMOUNT,
        COALESCE( T2.COST, 0 ) AS cost,
        T1.START_AMOUNT - COALESCE(T2.COST,0) as AVAILABLE
from    TABLE1 T1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT budget_category,
                 SUM( cost ) AS cost
          FROM   TABLE2
          GROUP BY
                 budget_category
        ) T2
        ON ( T1.BUDGET_CATEGORY = T2.BUDGET_CATEGORY )
order by BUDGET_CATEGORY;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( BUDGET_CATEGORY, START_AMOUNT ) AS
SELECT 'travel',    10000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'expenses',  20000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL   
SELECT 'equipment', 15000 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 ( ID_EXPENSES, COST, BUDGET_CATEGORY ) AS
SELECT 'city bus',  50, 'travel'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'car rent', 120, 'travel'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'computer', 800, 'equipment' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> BUDGET_CATEGORY | START_AMOUNT | COST | AVAILABLE
> :-------------- | -----------: | ---: | --------:
> equipment       |        15000 |  800 |     14200
> expenses        |        20000 |    0 |     20000
> travel          |        10000 |  170 |      9830
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=01d43c0922dc2e3a7658109f163772ca)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT T1.BUDGET_CATEGORY,
       T1.START_AMOUNT,
       T1.START_AMOUNT - SUM(T2.COST) AS AVAILABLE
  FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN  TABLE2 T2 ON T2.BUDGET_CATEGORY = T1.BUDGET_CATEGORY
GROUP BY T1.BUDGET_CATEGORY, T1.START_AMOUNT;
```